# Spring autowire not behaving as expected

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have tried to autowire a bean for a test class using `@Autowire`, however the bean is not wired and I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No matching bean of type [com.abc.MyDaoHibernateImpl] found for dependency: 
    expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
    dependency.
    Dependency annotations: 
        {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
package com.abc;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class MyDaoHibernateImplTest
    extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
{

    @Autowired
    private MyDaoHibernateImpl myDao;

    ....
}
```

The applicationContext.xml file has this bean definition:

```
<bean id="myDao" class="com.abc.MyDaoHibernateImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

--James

Answer (score 1):

As [axtavt suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754296/spring-autowire-not-behaving-as-expected/3754606#3754606), spring is a framework that heavily favors the use of interfaces. A spring best practice is to define a dependency to an interface and let spring inject the implementation. That's the whole point of dependency injection: you specify the interface you need, but the container will inject the implementation class it selects, which can either be a class you created or a dynamic proxy based on this class. But a class should not know the implementation details of it's dependency.

Here's a reference of the [Spring Proxying Mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types).

About the general concept of using interfaces, you should read [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Chapter 8, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces. Also, you should read [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html) from the Sun Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the actual type of your bean is obscured by [dynamic proxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) used to apply aspects. In this case you need to use interface rather than class for autowired fields (or force target class proxy strategy with `proxy-target-class="true"`).