# Converting code to Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am in the process of converting non-Spring code into Spring (v3.2) code. I have read through the Spring documentation but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following situation shown below.

Classes Foo and Buz are managed by Spring and are singletons.  Class Bar and MyHyperlinkListener need to be managed by Spring and should be prototype (though I'm not sure how to annotate these correctly).

- The instance of Buz inside of Bar is currently null because Bar is not being managed by Spring. How would these classes be correctly annotated to allow this?  Does a Factory class for Bar need to be created, and what would that look like?
- The constructor for Bar is being passed a 'this'(aka JFrame) from inside the Foo class.  I am not sure how to modify the code to handle a 'this' in Spring. I'm guessing this is another Factory that accepts a JFrame, but I'm not sure how to code that.

```
    @Named
    public class Foo extends JFrame{
        private Bar bar;

        private void doSomeWork(int x){
             bar = new Bar( new MyHyperlinkListener(this), x);
        }
    }

    public class Bar extends JPanel{
        @Inject
        private Buz buz;

        public Bar(MyHyperlinkListener mhl, int x){
        }
    }

    public class MyHyperlinkListener implements HyperlinkListener{
      private JFrame frame;
      public MyHyperlinkListener(JFrame frame){
        this.frame=frame;
      }
      //...code omitted
    }

    @Named
    public class Buz{
    }

    @Configuration
    public class MyConfiguration{

    }

    public class RunMe{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            context.scan("myPackage");
            context.refresh();
            context.registerShutdownHook();
            Foo foo = context.getBean(Foo.class);
            foo.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `Bar` class [@Configurable](http://aredko.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/using-configurable-in-spring-framework.html), which will allow it to be managed by Spring whenever an instance is created.

```
@Configurable
public class Bar extends JPanel{
    @Inject
    private Buz buz;

    public Bar(MyHyperlinkListener mhl, int x){
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a bean factory to create your instances of `Bar`. This will have the same effect:

```
@Configuration
public class BarFactory
{
  @Bean
  public Bar createBar(MyHyperlinkListener mhl, int x) {
    return new Bar(mhl, x);
  }
}
```

Both methods are valid, and mainly differ in how they expose the management. They will also allow the constructor you wish to use.

Comment: Thanks!  When I gave that a try I got new errors about No matching bean of type[MyHyperlinkListener]. I annotated the MyHyperlinkListener class with Configurable and the constructor with Inject, however I still got the same message.  I then made a createHyperlinkListener Bean inside the MyConfiguration class and called that instead of directly calling new MyHyperlinkListener from inside of Foo.

Comment: This gave me a new message about No unique bean of type [javax.swing.JFrame] is defined.  MyHyperLinkListener is called throughout the code from different JFrames, so I can't bind it to only one.  Any suggestions?  Am I even on the right track with what I've done since your suggestion?

Comment: Note - Configurable didn't work for me since I'd also need AspectJ, so I am using the Configuration way instead. I still get the 'No unique bean of type JFrame' messages though

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit about the set-up of @Configurable, the tutorial I linked to should explain how to set up AspectJ should you prefer to use it.

Comment: I have the classes named, but I still get that message.  I'm not sure how I would use the Spring's autowiring mode for this problem... and is it necessary (trying to stay agnostic as possible by using Named/Inject etc...)  For now I just created a specific createMyHyperLinkListener(Foo foo) to avoid the error.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment. This question explains that particular problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325448/spring-no-unique-bean-of-type (substitute the Spring annotations for your CDI ones as necessary). Spring bean naming strategies are really outside the scope of this question.